# Adding Rails dynamically via Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails form that includes a listbox

```
<div id = "tloList">
    <%= select_tag("task[tlo_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(TLO.all, "id", "statement"), :multiple => true, :onchange => "populateTasks()") %>.
</div>

<div id = "taskList">
</div>

<script>
  function populateTasks(){
     alert("CLICKED"); 
   }

<script>
```

After a user selects a TLO, I want to dynamically create another select tag for Tasks in the TaskList div. I've had no success with the following insider the populateTask() function by have had zero luck:

```
document.getElementById("taskList").insert(<%= select_tag("tlo[task_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(Task.all, "id", "statement"), :multiple => true %>);
```

Does anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: better pre render your select inside this hidden tasklist, and after click only show it, the error by the way is because "select_tag" is not javascript escaped what creates javascript errors

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an exception or is it not working as expected? It looks like your syntax is off. You may have an extra space in `options_from_collection_for select(TLO.all, "id", "statement")` Try this: `options_from_collection_for_select(TLO.all, "id", "statement")`

Also, where is your closing parens for your `select_tag`?

Comment: I edited it. My syntax and semantics are correct on my dev machine. So the issue is back to the javascript not the syntax and semantics.